# How to set color for each item listView

Tags: android, listview, colors, android-edittext

If I send a text, from my EditText, to my ListView I want to give that a color.
How am I supposed to do that?

Could I use HEX-code too?
This is what I tried so far.

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
    textBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textBox);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ArrayList<String> listViewList = new ArrayList<String>();

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listViewList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            adapter.add("Ik typte: " + textBox.getText().toString());
            adapter.remove(textBox.getText().toString());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create your own adapter like ArrayAdapter, with your own layout for each row.

Then, in that adapter, you can set the colors for each item in the getView method.